# Too stupid to understand random variable questions?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I have two excercises:

1.) Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be independent uniformly distributed random variables on $[0,1]$. What is the density function of $X_1+X_2+X_3$?

2.) Let $X_1,...,X_4$ be independet uniformly distributed random variables on $[0,1]$. What is the expectation value of $Y:=max\{X_1,...,X_4\}$?

To 1.) Well uniformly distributed r.v. means $P_{X_i}(A)=\int _A 1 dt$. So I would say that the constant density function stays the same (which is equal to 1) for the sum. This is perfectly reconcilable with the convolution. But this seems to be somehow to easy for an excercise, so am I missing anything?

To 2.) Well, my idea was to derive $P(Y \le t)$, which is the same as the product of those things for $X_1,...,X_4$(since they are independent). Therefore we have(by taking the derivative) $f_Y(t)=P(Y \le t)'=4t^3$ for $t \in [0,1]$ and $f_Y(t)=0$ elsewhere.

In principle I would say: $E(Y)= \int_0^1 t f_Y(t) dt$

But this cannot be correct here, since we have $E(Y):=\int Y(t) f(t) dt$ and we would require $Y$ to be differentiable in order to derive the equation two lines above. So, how can I proceed?

Comment: Regarding 1: Take a simpler case; let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be fair coin tosses, where heads=1 and tails=0. What is the distribution of $X_1+X_2$, the random variable gotten by flipping two coins and adding the results? Is it uniform?

Comment: @ThomasBelulovich sorry, I do not see how this is related to a uniform distributed random variable?

Comment: A Bernoulli variable with $p = 1/2$ can also be regarded as a discrete uniform variable on $[0,1]$, so in that regard, the sum of two Bernoulli variables is binomial, which is not uniform, suggesting that the sum of two uniform variables (continuous or discrete) would also not be uniform, but something else.

Comment: The coin toss is uniformly distributed over the discrete set $\{0,1\}.$ I find it can be helpful to think of discrete cases to build intuition a bit.

Comment: obviously I misunderstand what uniform distributed ranom variable actually means. could anybody explain this to me?

Comment: It is a random variable which has a constant density function.

Comment: yes okay, but this one must be equal to constant 1, right?

Comment: yes, because the integral must be 1. Do you understand why?

Comment: yes. But then the distribution of any sum is given by the convolution (says wikipedia)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions#Introduction

Comment: but why is the convolution of 3 constant 1 functions not a 1 function?

Comment: Well look at it this way. The first random variable takes value 0.75 the second one 0.6 and the third 0.9. The sum is 0.75 + 0.6 + 0.9. The lowest score you can obtain this way is 0+0+0, the higest 1+1+1 and each one is equally likely.

Comment: You therefore have a uniform distribution U[0,3], with density function $f(x) = 1/3$ for $0 \leq x \leq 3$.

Comment: ah, I see it. thanks...

Comment: I know it's difficult, it took me a long time to realise this too...

Comment: do you also have an idea regarding my second question?

Comment: Yeah, I posted an answer ;). I'm going to adress your reply there.

Comment: Since nobody mentioned it so far (although it was discussed in the comments and seems to be the real problem the OP is having), I should probably mention that the formula $E(Y):=\int Y(t)f(t)dt$ is **a monstrosity**. To the point that even imagining some $f$ which would make it true is nearly impossible... OP: What is your source for this?

Comment: sorry, are you sure that $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}$ is the solution to my question. Cause I got something different.

Comment: @Did you may have a look at the comments given by Leo. This formula can be proven by Radon-Nikodym as I found out.

Comment: @Lipschitz No it cannot. To think it could is at best delusional. Again: source? (Say, I see you prefer to simply neglect the comments that do not confirm your misconceptions rather than to address them. This might not be the best way to make progress--but hey, it's up to you.)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630823/expected-value-i-do-not-get-this-wikipedia-triviality

Comment: This is becoming tastier and tastier... Where do you see anything resembling Y(t) in the integrals written on the page you linked to? (Unrelated: use @, that is, unless you do not want to signal your new comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to the second question: I asked a similar question once:
[Density function of $\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468569/density-function-of-maxx-1-dots-x-n)

It is more abstract but I guess it could be interesting for you.

Comment: yes, but how did this person who answered your question derive $E(Y)=\int t f_Y(t) dt$ from $ E(Y)=\int Y(t) f(t) dt$ without running into difficulties?

Comment: He just plugs the desinty function $1$ and the distribution function $y$ into the formula I derived for the density function of the maximum of random variables. And with that info he continued to calculate the expected value.

Comment: Do you see my point? We did not define $E(Y)=\int tf_Y(t)$, just $E(Y)=\int Y(t) f(t) dt$

Comment: Oh, I think I get why you are confused now. Sorry, my mistake. The point is exactly that $f_Y(t) = n \cdot 1 \cdot t^{n-1}$. So $E[max(X_1, \cdots ,  X_n)] = \int t f_Y(t) dt = \int n t^n dt$.

Comment: Where $Y= max(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$. It's getting late central european time.

Comment: Yes, but I do not know the equation that says $E(Y)=\int t f_Y(t)dt$, we just did not the define the expectation value that way, we said $E(Y)=\int Y(t) f(t) dt$, which means that I am not supposed to use this first equation that is used in your thread..

Comment: For this case the definitions are equivalent, you're using a more general one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

Comment: But how are they equivalent? I mean Y is not a differentiable function, so you cannot just substitute it away.

Comment: If you read from 'Univariate continuous random variable' onwards, you'll see that it's the same for this case.

Comment: Do you know how to actually show this?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with your notation, so I don't think I can do it formally (taking into account all subtilties of measure theory) off the top of my hat. However it only seems reasonable reading the wikipedia page.

Comment: I mean, I noticed that it is in principle the substitution rule, IF Y would be differentiable, which is just not true. This is actually my problem with this whole excercise.

Comment: mmm... could you make $Y$ explicit for me? Cause to me it just is the random variable.

Comment: I defined $Y=max\{X_1,...,X_4\}$ above, sorry. Do we know anything for uniform distributed randomn variables. Are they for example necessarily continuous?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't see how to prove the equivalence of our definitions. Maybe it's a good question to post here on math.SE...

Comment: thank you, I will dot. thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As to the first question, lets look at the CDF of $X$:
$$F(x) = P(X>x)= P(X_3>x-X_1-X_2)$$
This is just the volume of the [intersection of a cube and a plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454583/volume-of-cube-section-above-intersection-with-plane):
$$F(x) = 1-x^3/6\quad \to \quad p(x) = -x^2/2$$